# Color transition not working with setTimeout. Element should appear smoothy

Tags: javascript, css, settimeout, transition

Color transition works, if I don't hide the element and then make it appear.

```js
const name = document.querySelector(".name");

setTimeout(() => {
  name.classList.remove("hide");
  name.classList.add("color-blue")
  // name.style.color = "blue";
}, 2000)
```

```css
.name {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: color 10s;
  color: transparent;
}
.color-blue { color: blue; }

.hide { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="name hide">
  Lebron James
</div>
```

If I don't use the class hide and I don't remove it later, the transition works. By hiding it, it does not work.

No clue what's going on

Thanks for your help

Comment: change `hide` to `opacity:0` and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is working code

```js
const name = document.querySelector(".name");

setTimeout(() => {
  name.classList.remove("hide");
  name.classList.add("color-blue")
  // name.style.color = "blue";
}, 2000)
```

```css
.name {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: color 10s;
  color: transparent;
}
.color-blue { color: blue; }

.hide { opacity: 0 }
```

```html
<div class="name hide">
  Lebron James
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/39pdLarn/2/

the display has limitations in animated BUT you can use visibility and opacity for transitions.

Comment: hey... the link does not work

Answer (score 0):

**Use `opacity` set `opacity:0` to hide element.**

Learn about `opacity`:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

```js
const name = document.querySelector(".name");

setTimeout(() => {
  name.classList.remove("hide");
  name.classList.add("color-blue")
  // name.style.color = "blue";
}, 2000)
```

```css
.name {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: color 10s;
  color: transparent;
}
.color-blue { color: blue; }

.hide { opacity:0; }
```

```html
<div class="name hide">
  Lebron James
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get why my strategy was wrong. Why it does not work from display none to display inline-block

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using `display: none;`.

CSS cannot show animation if you set `display` to `none`. You can make use of `opacity: 0` to hide the element but remember to add that to `transition` as well otherwise it will not show any color transition.

```js
const name = document.querySelector(".name");

setTimeout(() => {
  name.classList.add("hide");
  name.classList.add("color-blue")
  // name.style.color = "blue";
}, 2000);
```

```css
.name {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: color 10s, opacity 10s;
  color: transparent;
}

.color-blue {
  color: blue;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  Lebron James
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `display: none` (i.e, remove the element from DOM) then you can update your JS code as follow:

```js
const name = document.querySelector(".name");

setTimeout(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    name.classList.add("hide");
  }, 10000);
  name.classList.add("color-blue")
  // name.style.color = "blue";
}, 2000)
```

```css
.name {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: color 10s;
  color: transparent;
}

.color-blue {
  color: blue;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  Lebron James
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Surprisingly, with opacity: 0 from the begining, the element does not occupy space in the DOM so I don't need the extra setTimeout
2) I find weird that I get rid of the class hide with display none, because then the display has the value inline-block. I don't get why the displays do not work with animations

Comment: 3) I need to use opacity !important, if I want to make it work. Why?